# ZF2: Listen for an MVC Exception, then Redirect

Tags: model-view-controller, error-handling, zend-framework2

In my ZF2 application I sometimes throw a `LoginRequired` exception.  I want to catch this exception and use it to redirect the user to a login page.  How should I do this?

The error is usually thrown by my service layer.  It is usually thrown during dispatch, but could also be thrown during render, since there is a view helper which calls some service layer methods (e.g. to get the current user).

I would have thought it was a simple matter of using the module's bootstrap method to attach a listener to the `dispatch.error` and `render.error` events.  I was then planning to test for a `LoginRequired` exception, but I can't seem to get hold of the actual exception.  (`$mvcEvent->getResult()->exception` returns `null`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an example listener aggregate that should be of help.

The difference is my listener uses configuration and the matched route name in order to determine if the redirect should occur. You could instead, during `dispatch.error`, fetch the exception from MVC event using `$mvcEvent->getParam('exception')` and check that.

```
use ArpAuth\Service\AuthenticationService;
use ArpAuth\Service\AuthenticationServiceAwareTrait;
use Zend\Console\Console;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\Http\Response;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;
use Zend\EventManager\AbstractListenerAggregate;


class NoAuthRedirectStrategy extends AbstractListenerAggregate
{

    protected $whitelistRoutes = [];
    protected $redirectRoute = 'user/auth/login';

    use AuthenticationServiceAwareTrait;

    public function __construct(AuthenticationService $authenticationService, array $options = [])
    {
        $this->authenticationService = $authenticationService;

        if (! empty($options)) {
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }
    }


    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $eventManager)
    {
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, [$this, 'isAuthenticated'], 1000);
    }

    public function isAuthenticated(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $routeMatch = $event->getRouteMatch();

        if (Console::isConsole() || ! $routeMatch instanceof RouteMatch) {
            return;
        }

        $serviceManager  = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $currentRoute    = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
        $isRemoteApiCall = $serviceManager->get('IsRemoteApiCall');

        if ($this->hasWhitelistRoute($currentRoute) || $isRemoteApiCall || $this->authenticationService->hasIdentity()) {
            return;
        }

        $router = $event->getRouter();
        /** @var Response $response */
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        $url = $router->assemble([], ['name' => $this->redirectRoute]);

        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
        $response->setStatusCode(302);

        return $response;
    }

    public function setRedirectRoute($redirectRoute)
    {
        $this->redirectRoute = $redirectRoute;

        return $this;
    }

    public function hasWhitelistRoute($route)
    {
        return (! empty($route) && in_array($route, $this->whitelistRoutes));
    }

    public function getWhitelistRoutes()
    {
        return $this->whitelistRoutes;
    }

    public function setWhitelistRoutes(array $routes)
    {
        $this->whitelistRoutes = [];

        return $this->addWhitelistRoutes($routes);
    }

    public function addWhitelistRoutes(array $routes)
    {
        foreach($routes as $route) {
            $this->addWhitelistRoute($route);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function addWhitelistRoute($route)
    {
        if (! $this->hasWhiteListRoute($route)) {
            $this->whitelistRoutes[] = $route;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        if (isset($options['whitelist']) && is_array($options['whitelist'])) {
            $this->setWhitelistRoutes($options['whitelist']);
        }

        if (isset($options['redirect_route'])) {
            $this->setRedirectRoute($options['redirect_route']);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks AlexP.  How did you know that 'exception' was an event parameter?  That's really helpful.

Comment: @kim Check out the ['dispatch listener'](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/DispatchListener.php#L131), which is the main event listener for dispatching controllers.